# How to remove this li element from an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below in my list, one of the divs at the bottom has a `removePortfolio` function. This function's job is to activate the `ng-hide="tickerRemoved"` but only for that 1 list item, not all the list items.

**HTML Gist:** https://gist.github.com/leongaban/cf72e5d0229155dd011f
**Directive Gist:** https://gist.github.com/leongaban/22a8feb9dbeea0b90135

```
<ul ng-show="loadingTickersDone" class="tickers-list">

    <li class="ticker-li"
        ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
        ng-hide="tickerRemoved"
        ng-class="{'selected':toggleTicker.item == $index}"
        ng-mouseleave="hideTickerOptions()">

        <div class="ticker"
             ng-click="toggleTicker.item = $index;
                       selectTicker(ticker.ticker);
                       revealTickerOptions()">
             {{ticker.ticker}}
        </div>

        <div class="add-to-portfolio"
             ng-show="tickerOptions"
             ng-mouseleave="hideTickerOptions()">

             <div ng-show="addOption"
                  ng-click="addPortfolio(ticker.ticker)">+ Portfolio</div>
             <div ng-show="removeOption"
                  ng-click="removePortfolio(ticker.ticker)">- Portfolio</div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Here is the remove function in the directive:

```
var vs = $scope;

vs.removePortfolio = function(ticker) {
    this.tickerOptions = false;
    ApiFactory.deleteWatchList(ticker).then(function(data) {
        showMessage(ticker+' removed from portfolio!', data.data.status);
        this.tickerRemoved = true;
    });
};
```

I get an error with `this.tickerRemoved = true;` I think this is because the scope is lower in the chain?

[image]

For example, I'm using `this` in this function and it works fine because the function is higher in the markup/scope:

```
vs.revealTickerOptions = function() {
    this.tickerOptions = true;

    if (tickerView === 'all') {
        this.addOption    = true;
        this.removeOption = false;
    }
    else if (tickerView === 'port') {
        this.addOption    = false;
        this.removeOption = true;
    }
};
```

How would I remove just the 1 `<li class="ticker-li"` item when clicking the `removePortfolio()` function?

Comment: The error with `this.tickerRemoved = true;` is because `this`, in your example, refers to the function. You need to bind the function: `.then(function(data) { /* ... your code */ }.bind(this))` . However, it looks like it would affect every ticker - you probably want something more like `ticker.removed = true;` and `ng-hide="ticker.removed"` . You'd then also need to pass the actual ticker object in the `ng-click` code: `ng-click="removePortfolio(ticker)"`.

Comment: Ah that was a cool idea! I just tried it but got this error `Cannot assign to read only property 'removed' of XOM` going to play with it a bit more

Comment: Ignore the whole first part, that was just explaining the reason that you were getting an error. Focus on the latter half. Pass the `ticker` object, I assume it looks like `tickers =[{ticker: "aapl"}]`, pass the whole thing so that you can add a `removed` property: `{ticker: "aapl", removed: true}` , that way you can hide just that one. Either that or actually remove it from the array, use `slice`.

Comment: OH it worked! :D I need to clean up somethings here.. sec, ah yeah @AlexMA has it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-hide="tickerRemoved"` should be `ng-hide="ticker.tickerRemoved"` since tickerRemoved is a property of a specific ticker.

Same with `ng-show="tickerOptions"`... should be `ng-show="ticker.tickerOptions"` from the looks of it.

`ng-click="removePortfolio(ticker.ticker)">` should be `ng-click="removePortfolio(ticker)">` since you probably want to pass the entire ticker object.

After that, you will need to update your remove ticker function, something like this should work:

```
vs.removePortfolio = function(tickerObject) {
    var ticker = tickerObject.ticker
    tickerObject.tickerOptions = false;
    ApiFactory.deleteWatchList(ticker).then(function(data) {
        showMessage(ticker+' removed from portfolio!', data.data.status);
        tickerObject.tickerRemoved = true;
    });
};
```

As a general observation, it looks like you are leaning on `this` too much.  `this` can be a very confusing keyword and should only be used (in my opinion) when there is both a good reason to do so and doing so will not cause confusion during later code maintenance.

Comment: How would I target just the 1 ng-repeated item, instead of all the items?

Comment: `ticker` in `vs.removePortfolio = function(ticker) {` is only passed the the ticker clicked, so there should be no issue.

Comment: Ah, I see a few more issues.  Let me change my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant hehe... I thought I'd have to do some strange $parent $scope thing or something lol, love Angular